# Resizing Image Without Average Color

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, python-imaging-library

I would like to be able to reduce a (300 x 300) photo to (10 x 10) size, while maintaining the cell colors with the original, and the positioning of the cells to be approximately at the same position.

I have a (300 x 300) pixels image that is in a heatmap format. I have reduced the colors of the heatmap to only 3 colors for easier representation:

[image: Original Image].

Now I have to resize it in a (10 x 10). If I do it using

```
resized = cv2.resize(img, (ws,hs), interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)
```

It gives me average color, which I do not want. I want my original 3 colors to stay is somewhat approximate place:

[image: Average Colored Image]

The closest I have reached is this image below, but the position of the pixels are somewhat messy. The average color image has the position of the pixels very close to the original photo.

[image: Color maintained Image]

My Code So Far:

```
normal = [68, 2, 85]
minor = [44, 114, 142]
major = [232, 228, 29]
```

[A bit of explanation: The image is in (300 x 300) array, instead of rgb value, only r value is saved, but as there are only 3 colors with different reds, a new image can be reproduced easily. (300 x 300) array is divided and iterated by a 30*30 draft array, which takes total of 900 pixel values, and converts it into 1 cell for the (10 x 10) array. The priority for color goes: Major>Minor>Normal. If Major is found in the (30 x 30) array, the cell of (10 x 10) is colored as major and so on]

[data_2_2_dim is the (300 x 300) array, and data_3_2_dim is the (10 x 10) array]

```py
iter1 = 0 
iter2 = 0 

for i in range(data_3_2_dim.shape[0]):
    for j in range(data_3_2_dim.shape[1]):
        draft = np.zeros((30, 30))
        val_no = 0 
        val_minor = 0
        val_major = 0
        for k in range(30): 
            for l in range(30): 
                # val = 68
                if data_2_2_dim[iter1][iter2] == 44 and data_2_2_dim[iter1][iter2] != 232: 
                    val = 44 
                    
                if data_2_2_dim[iter1][iter2] == 232: 
                    val = 232 
                    
                if data_2_2_dim[iter1][iter2] == 68 and data_2_2_dim[iter1][iter2] != 232 and data_2_2_dim[iter1][iter2] != 44: 
                    val = 68 
                    
                draft[k][l] = val

        
            iter1+=1
        
        major = False 
        minor = False
        
        for p in range(draft.shape[0]): 
            for q in range(draft.shape[1]): 
                if draft[p][q] == 232: 
                    major = True
                if draft[p][q] == 44: 
                    minor = True
        
        if minor == True and major == False: 
            data_3_2_dim[j][i] = 44 
        elif major == True: 
            data_3_2_dim[j][i] = 232
        else: 
            data_3_2_dim[j][i] = 68 
            
        
        iter2+=1
    iter1 = 0

from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import colors
import numpy as np

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.imshow(data_3_2_dim) 
plt.show()
```

Comment: You need to defined the *interpolation method* you precisely want. It looks like you want the colour of the largest group of associated pixels in the source image. This is called a mode. It is not very frequent for computing images but more frequent in statistics (especially when people work on labels/classes like you seems to do).

Comment: @JérômeRichard Can you provide me one example or link, from where I can have a bit of demonstration of this interpolation. Thank you.

Comment: Use  cv2.INTER_NEAREST

Comment: @fmw42, tried it, but doesn't yield good result unfortunately. Thanks tho

Comment: It sounds like you're just looking for the max in each 30x30 window, is that correct?

Comment: @breaker, yes something like that. Say, if there's a value of Major or Minor in the 30*30 matrix, the cell (at 10*10) will take that color, else, it'll just be normal. 

But, unfortunately, this way the approx. position of the actual cells doesn't seem to follow (given in photo 3). 

I want the photo to look like Photo 3, but the Color positions to be like Photo 2

Comment: Is it important that any pixel with a Major value in its portion of the original image be Major, or was that just part of your attempt?

Comment: It is important @DavisHerring

Comment: @MoontasirSoumik: Then how can the answer be anything other than your (second) approach?

Comment: You can just start with [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mode_(statistics)) and then use [Scipy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.mode.html) so to compute that.

Comment: Thank you everyone. I appreciate the time you invested in this post. I will just go with the solution I have at hand. If I calculate the area of each color in the 300*300 and compare the ration with 10*10, they are somewhat similar, and I think it's good enough for now

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it asks for a solution beyond what is given, but the constraints preclude any other algorithm.